# Can treaties between the Crown and Indigenous peoples have force absent an act of Parliament?

Tags: canada, aboriginal-law

Can treaties between the Crown and Indigenous peoples have force absent an act of Parliament?

Answer (score 4):

The recognition of Parliament is not necessary for a treaty, which is a solemn agreement, to have force in law. As just one example of many in the history of the land that would become Canada, see the "[Treaty of 1752](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_1752)." It was discussed by the Supreme Court of Canada in *Simon v. The Queen*, [[1985] 2 S.C.R. 387 at para. 24](https://canlii.ca/t/1fv04#par24):

> The Treaty was entered into for the benefit of both the British Crown and the Micmac people, to maintain peace and order as well as to recognize and confirm the existing hunting and fishing rights of the Micmac. In my opinion, both the Governor and the Micmac entered into the Treaty with the intention of creating mutually binding obligations which would be solemnly respected. It also provided a mechanism for dispute resolution. The Micmac Chief and the three other Micmac signatories, as delegates of the Micmac people, would have possessed full capacity to enter into a binding treaty on behalf of the Micmac. Governor Hopson was the delegate and legal representative of His Majesty The King. It is fair to assume that the Micmac would have believed that Governor Hopson, acting on behalf of His Majesty The King, had the necessary authority to enter into a valid treaty with them. I would hold that the Treaty of 1752 was validly created by competent parties.

Of course today, the rights secured by treaty have been constitutionalized through the *Constitution Act, 1982*, a Schedule to an Act of the British Parliament. And a close read of Section 35 reveals that it is not what creates treaty rights. The *treaty* creates the rights — section 35 recognizes and affirms the *existing* treaty rights, protecting them from extinguishment or unjustified infringement. As the Court said in *Mitchell v. M.N.R.*, 2001 SCC 33 (emphasis added; internal citations removed):

> [The] situation changed in 1982, when Canada’s constitution was amended to *entrench existing aboriginal and treaty rights*. The enactment of s. 35(1) *elevated* existing common law aboriginal rights to constitutional status.

What changed in 1982 was entrenchment, not existence, of the treaty rights. Thus, even before treaty rights were protected by the *Constitution Act, 1982*, the validity and force of treaties entered into with Indigenous peoples has long been recognized in Canadian law. This was without an act of Parliament mandating this recognition. See e.g. *St. Catharines Milling and Lumber Co. v. R.* (1887), [13 S.C.R. 577](https://scc-csc.lexum.com/scc-csc/scc-csc/en/3769/1/document.do).

Answer (score 1):

In the context of Canada: this is an academic question at this point, as there is an Act of the UK Parliament that recognizes these treaties.

The Constitution Act 1982 contains:

Section 25: The guarantee in this Charter of certain rights and freedoms shall not be construed so as to abrogate or derogate from any aboriginal, treaty or other rights or freedoms that pertain to the aboriginal peoples of Canada...

And furthermore

Section 35(1)The existing aboriginal and treaty rights of the aboriginal peoples of Canada are hereby recognized and affirmed.

As such, it is purely hypothetical to consider the situation if this Act did not exist.

Comment: I almost started off with calling this a "moot point", but upon further research, it turns out that the technical legal definitions are opposite between American and British contexts.

Comment: "False friends" are a constant peril when shifting between American English and British English.